# undefined ответ на get запрос к своему API на aws lambda

Tags: javascript, node.js

Написал и задеплоил на AWS свой API.
При запросе с браузера или через Postman - ответ приходит. Status 200 -ok

При get запросе из локального приложения на node js - получаю undefined. Почему?

```
const axios = require('axios');

axios.get('https://2nnpsk9po1.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/times/')
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response.data.url);
    console.log(response.data.explanation);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Comment: а ответ может в json приходит?

Comment: то, что вы получаете undefined в консоль вовсе не означает, что ответ не с кодом 200